# Can somebody help me identify this Japanese display font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, japanese

[image]

Font identification websites don't seem to be able to recognize non-latin characters. Google search also hasn't given me any results.

Comment: I allways wonder when people search for japanese fonts that do  the know how expensive licenses for chinese and japanese fonts are?

Comment: @joojaa I am just looking for the font's name, if hypothetically I wanted to buy the license I would still have to know what the actual font is ^^

Answer (score 2):

This is [コミックレゲエ](https://fontworks.co.jp/fontsearch/comicreggaestd-b/) (or perhaps [レゲエ](https://fontworks.co.jp/fontsearch/reggaestd-b/)) from a major type foundry フォントワークス (Fontworks). The only difference between them is the stroke contrast, which is somewhat hard to tell due to the outline effect and resolution.

[image]
[image]

They provide subscription and web font services at least in Japan, as far as I know.