# Identify Japanese Font, Help Please

Tags: font-identification, japanese

Can someone help me find the Japanese font used in this Boku no Hero Academia screenshot?[image]

I have tried looking for this font everywhere including font recognizing systems but I'd had no luck.

Comment: Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/140776/35722

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I spent hours looking, and I think the closest (and free) font I could find is called "Reggae One".